# After running Brew Update, mysql was updated, all rails applications with mysql2 don't work

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, homebrew

I have been on this issue for some time now. It happened after I ran brew upgrade. It installed mysql version 5.7.9.

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@AppName/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@AppName/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/MyName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@AppName/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/mysql2-0.3.20/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
```

but when I cd into the directory

```
opt/mysql/lib  master ✔                                                                                                                                                                             3h36m
▶ ls
libmysqlclient.18.dylib libmysqlclient.20.dylib libmysqlclient.a        libmysqlclient.dylib    libmysqld.a             libmysqlservices.a      pkgconfig               plugin
```

I tried all the symlink answers on this forum but still no luck. I am running El Capitan. I also did locate and this was the result:

```
opt/mysql/lib  master ✔                                                                                                                                                                             3h36m
▶ locate libmysqlclient.18.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.27/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

The gem mysql2 is not working for any of my rails applications. Everytime I run rails s, or any rake task it automatically fails. Running rails s gives this error:

```
▶ rails s
bin/rails:6: warning: already initialized constant APP_PATH
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated. Please and thank you.

Comment: Bummer, Try running `which mysql`,`which rails` etc to see if it returns anything. Also check to see if rails is still installed by running `rails -v`

Comment: I fixed it by reinstalling mysql from brew, then uninstalled and reinstalled the mysql2 gem from each of my versions of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

so I wanted to make sure this was there for others with this problem. [Wajid Kagzi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4724762/wajid-kagzi)'s comment was the fix for my issue as well.

> I fixed it by reinstalling mysql from brew, then uninstalled and reinstalled the mysql2 gem from each of my versions of ruby.